# package-selected-packages variable not being automatically updated?

Tags: package

I noticed that after I edited my package-selected-packages by hand it no longer gets automatically updated when I install a package with package-install command.  How do I get it back to updating automatically?

Comment: Did you add something or take something out? No reason why editing it should affect package, unless you bunged up the formatting somehow. You can look at it in Customize, see if you can spot anything out of the ordinary. It stands to reason that you would want to be able to edit it, since not everything comes through package.

Comment: Well yes, I did add something, I added a package to the list when I edited it.  I don't see anything odd in Customize.  Also by editing it I meant I changed the part in my init.el that begins with "(custom-set-variables", I'm pretty sure I kept the formatting still correct.  Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I tried it myself and it worked - that is, I put in a dummy package and then installed a new package and the new package shows up in `package-selected-packages`. Do you have flycheck? You could use it to look for errors in the elisp.

Comment: I installed flycheck and it didn't spot any errors.  Starting emacs with -debug-init doesn't give me anything either, the syntax seems to be fine.